# Custom Move in construction heuristic

Tags: optaplanner

Is there a way to put a custom move in a construction heuristic?
I am working on a project that is close to the nurse rostering problem in optaplanner, but besides just putting the employee to a shift assignment i also need to put the employee to small assignments that are required within a shift.
So when i put the employee within a shift i need to put the employee in all the small assignments that he can work on (has the skill for them). I don't want that to be a second planning entity and the employee being the planning variable, i just want when i assign the employee to a shift then loop trough all the small assignments that are within that shift(are between the start and end times of the shift) and either assign him or not, so if he has the skill he must be assigned ,otherwise not.
I'm having trouble putting this custom move in the construction heuristic. Is there a way?

EDIT :
Will it be good to put a "price tag" on every shift ,by this i mean run through a pre optaplanner heuristic (before the solving starts) which counts the number occurrences of small assignments in every shift.Then later use this information to decide if an employee will be good for that shift or not, lets say he can be assigned to a given shift if he has the skills to meet at least 70% of the small assignments.For example we have the next small assignments (SA) that occur within the time of the shift : SA1 4 occurrences , SA2 4 occurrences , SA3 2 occurrences , and we have employee1 who has skills for SA1 and SA2 and employee2 who has only the skill for SA1, then employee1 can be assigned to the shift because he meets more than 70% small assignments ,but employee2 can't because he only meets 40%. Then after the employee gets "in" the shift just assign him to all the assignments that he can work (if he has the skill for the small assignment he will work on it, there will be no constraints for the small assignments besides the employee to have the skill required). There won't be a decision which employee to put on a small assignment ,every employee will be the same, if he got assigned to the shift and has the skill.
Is this a good idea to do?

And also can there be multiple planning values assigned to a single instance of the planning entity? In this case can there be multiple employees assigned to a single shift assignment instance(i'm just taking it as an example, i'm not planning to make it that way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the advanced configuration of Construction Heuristics in the docs. **Construction Heuristics only work with ChangeMove's and combinations (cartesian, union, sequence) thereof.** For example, if you have 2 entities A and B (each with 1 variable) with 10 A instances and 7 B instances, it's possible:

- To have 2 CH's: the first CH assigns all A's and afterwards the second assigns all B's. So it assigns in this order: A1, A2, A3, ..., A10, B1, B2, ..., B7 (and for each it tries every planning value).
- To have 1 CH's that assigns a mixture of A and B. So it assigns in a mixed order (defined by the entity sorter): A1, B1, B2, A2, B4, A3, ..., B7, A10.
- (If there's only 1 entity class but 2 variables, it's possible to do a cartesian product or a sequential assigning.)

Anyway, if that doesn't cut it, **implement a CustomPhaseCommand for full freedom** (see docs and examples that have an `...Initializer` class).

> besides just putting the employee to a shift assignment i also need to
>   put the employee to small assignments that are required within a shift

Sounds like your model might be inefficient. Consider alternative models to have only 1 planning variable:

```
class Employee {}
class Shift {}
@PlanningEntity class SmallAssignment {
    Shift shift;
    @PlanningVariable Employee employee;
}
```

Or better define what a "shift" is: if 2 people work at the same time, do they use the same shift instance? As your business complexity might need this model:

```
class Employee {}
class ShiftWithDateTime {}
@PlanningEntity lass ShiftWithDateTimeAndEmployee {
    ShiftWithDateTime shiftWithDateTime;
    @PlanningVariable Employee employee;
}
@PlanningEntity class SmallAssignment {
    ShiftWithDateTime shiftWithDateTime;
    @PlanningVariable Employee employee;
}
```

But in that case, I'd might check if it's refactorable like this (which is only possible if the small assignments can be perfectly assigned greedly, so their constraints aren't NP-hard):

```
class Employee {}
@PlanningEntity class ShiftWithDateTime { // shadow entity
    @InverseRelationShadow List<ShiftWithDateTimeAndEmployee> assignments;
    boolean hasEnoughEmployeesToFulfillAllSmallAssignments() { ... }
}
@PlanningEntity lass ShiftWithDateTimeAndEmployee {
    ShiftWithDateTime shiftWithDateTime;
    @PlanningVariable Employee employee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. I have put another question as an edit which is an addition to the same question.